# EWS Autodiscover fails with Error 401

Tags: exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

I am sitting in front of the following log, and I don't know where the Error 401 comes from:

```
Scanning for SCP urls for the current computer Site=Berlin
Adding (prio 1) 'https://SERVER3.CONTOSO.DE/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml' for the 'Site=Berlin' from 'LDAP://CN=SERVER3,CN=Autodiscover,CN=Protocols,CN=SERVER3,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Contoso,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=CONTOSO,DC=DE' to the top of the list (exact match)
Determining which endpoints are enabled for host server3.contoso.de
Request error: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
Host returned enabled endpoint flags: Legacy, Soap, WsSecurity
```

Which server is returning the 401 there? And which URL is called?

Furthermore, I sometimes have SCP lookups failing. Then, the query is:

```
Determining which endpoints are enabled for host contoso.de
Request error: Die Verbindung mit dem Remoteserver kann nicht hergestellt werden.
No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host contoso.de
```

Which server returns the request error? (Or which URLs should I try from browser to nail down which server is failing?) Since I have to wait for a 40sec timeout, I would like to fix the server that EWS can't connect to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that server3.contoso.de is failing in the first example, and that contoso.de is failing in the second.